# Conversion from string to list in Prolog

Tags: bash, prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to use a piece of software and I'm running into some problems.

It's worth noting that using university computers which have prolog preinstalled(OSX) or Windows computers the same piece of software works. While it does not work on my Linux/Ubuntu machine.

The software starts up with a bash script using this form:

```
echo "reset_statistics(off), specific_load_predicate(filename), tokenize(\"$2\", List), tex(List, $3)." | ./prolog-executable
```

The prolog executable is created using `swipl -c` and `qsave_program/1`

Now I found out the predicate tokenize is of the form:

```
tokenize([A|As], List) :- ...
```

So it takes a list as input, but the bash script provides a String.

Is it possible using some sort of prolog module or extension that would automatically make the conversion from string to list? Because the same code works on other computers.

Comment: In SWI-Prolog, set the Prolog flag `double_quotes` to `chars` (recommended) or `codes` to turn everything within double quotes into a list of characters or codes. This is how it **should** have been in the first place, and what also other Prolog systems do. You can also use the command line option `--traditional` to get standard-conforming behaviour in this regard.

Comment: @mat Great! this was the kind of answer I was looking for. It works when I start up swipl with --traditional but it doesn't work with all the bash scripts that are being used, is there any way to set it system-wide?

Comment: You can add a Bash alias, for example: `alias swipl='/usr/local/bin/swipl --traditional'`, or put `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).` in your `~/.swiplrc`. Note this all leads to extremely fun situations when your instructor uses a different way to invoke SWI-Prolog. It's almost as if there should be a standard for Prolog!

Comment: The bash alias doesn't work because the the bash scripts use the absolute path. But I got one step further adding set_prolog_flag to my .swiplrc. Now I get `ERROR: </2: Arithmetic: \`'I'/0' is not a function` Could that be caused by a similar prolog flag?

Comment: Probably you have some code that relies on `double_quotes` being set to `codes`, you can try that. Note that ideally, library code should be written to work with **both** `chars` and `codes`! Historically, `chars` was the first and preferable option (i.e., double quotes were treated as a list of **characters**); later, this was changed to `codes`, and I think the long-term best option is to come back again to `chars` at last. So, short term, set `double_quotes` to `codes` in order to work around the SWI 7 problems, and make your future code safe to work with `chars`!

Comment: Using `codes` does do the trick, but it seems like other parts of the source has a problem with this: `ERROR: char_code/2: Cannot represent due to \`character_code'` I'm just using the program for exercises in class, so fortunately I don't have to work the the code. But I hear what you're saying :)

Comment: You need to track down all places where the code expects different behaviour for double quotes. Since you probably have to modify several different places in any case, my recommendation is to: (1) put `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).` in your `~/.swiplrc`. **chars** is recommended, since it leads to very readable lists of *characters*. And (2), track down and modify all places that still expect lists of *codes*, and modify them to work correctly with *characters* too. Eventually, you will end up with nicely readable programs, which is what was originally intended in Prolog.

Comment: I had removed a `2> /dev/null` line to see the errors, and apparantly the last error message I got was 'as intented' -.- Thanks for your help it works now! If you make it into an answer I can mark it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SWI-Prolog unfortunately deviates from the Prolog ISO standard in that what is surrounded by *double quotes* is no longer a list of *character codes*.

To restore the compliant behaviour in this respect, use one of the following methods:

1. invoke SWI-Prolog with the `--traditional` flag
2. add `:- initialization(set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes)).` to your source file.
3. add `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).` to your `~/.swiplrc` initialization file.

In fact, instead of going with lists of character codes, I recommend you take a different route altogether and adapt your programs to use **lists of characters**, which means that each character is represented by an atom. This has the great advantage that toplevel answers remain very similar to what appears in queries, and are in fact quite readable by themselves. You obtain lists of *characters* for example by putting:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
```

in your `~/.swiplrc` initialization file. With the value **chars**, you get for example:

```
?- Cs = "hello".
Cs = [h, e, l, l, o].
```

I recommend you use this value, and adapt your existing programs to work with lists of characters. Long-term, I think this will be the the best and most widely used approach, which was historically also what double-quotes were *meant* to denote.

Until we get (back) there, you can use one of the methods above (i.e., switch to **codes** as an intermediate solution, to at least work around the problems introduced by SWI 7), then adapt your libraries to work with codes **and** characters, and then, at last, switch to *characters*.